# azure pipeline publish dotnet core remote host

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops

I'm using azure pipeline to build and deploy my Asp.net core project to remote server,I successfully build and publish files to artifact staging folder ,and then I use ftp upload task to upload files to remote server, but the problem is all the files are in the same folder and wwwroot folder is not there so website breaks because of the css and js files.

[image]
but when I use the 'zipAfterPublish=true', it generates the right files and folder
[image]
this is my yml file :
`

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  ftpServer : '*****'
  ftpUsername : '*****'
  ftpPassword  : '****'
  ftpRootDirectory : '*****'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
  displayName: 'dotnet build $(buildConfiguration)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    arguments: '-c $(buildConfiguration) -o $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/published'
    publishWebProjects: true
    zipAfterPublish: false
  displayName: 'publish $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/published'  

- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  inputs:
    targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/published'
    publishLocation: 'pipeline'
  displayName: 'publish artifact to pipeline'  
- task: FtpUpload@2
  inputs:
    credentialsOption: 'inputs'
    serverUrl: '$(ftpServer)'
    username: '$(ftpUsername)'
    password: '$(ftpPassword)'
    rootDirectory: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    remoteDirectory: '$(ftpRootDirectory)'
    filePatterns: '**/*.htm'
    clean: false
    cleanContents: false
    preservePaths: false
    trustSSL: false
  displayName: 'Upload App_Offline'
- task: FtpUpload@2
  inputs:
    credentialsOption: 'inputs'
    serverUrl: '$(ftpServer)'
    username: '$(ftpUsername)'
    password: '$(ftpPassword)'
    rootDirectory: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/published'
    filePatterns: '**'
    remoteDirectory: '$(ftpRootDirectory)'
    clean: false
    cleanContents: false
    preservePaths: false
    trustSSL: false
  displayName: 'Upload Publish Files'
- task: FtpUpload@2
  inputs:
    credentialsOption: 'inputs'
    serverUrl: '$(ftpServer)'
    username: '$(ftpUsername)'
    password: '$(ftpPassword)'
    rootDirectory: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    filePatterns: '**.ddddd'
    remoteDirectory: '$(ftpRootDirectory)'
    clean: false
    cleanContents: false
    preservePaths: false
    trustSSL: false
    customCmds: 'DELE /***/App_Offline.htm'
  displayName: 'Delete App_Offline'
```

`

I already tried a few things but none of them worked for me .
help please ?

Comment: Please read the documentation to learn what is "preservePaths".

Comment: @raminazadi you can refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/ftp-upload-v2?view=azure-pipelines and share your answer for others meet this problem.

Answer (score 0):

As @lexli shared, you can check the "preservePaths":

For example, suppose your source folder is /home/user/source/, which contains the file foo/bar/foobar.txt, and your remote directory is: /uploads/. If this boolean is selected, the file is uploaded to /uploads/foo/bar/foobar.txt. If this boolean is not selected, the file is uploaded to /uploads/foobar.txt.

For more information, you could refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/ftp-upload-v2?view=azure-pipelines